# ASP.NET MVC Attribute routing and localization

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Trying to set up attribute routing combined with culture in URI.

I want to set up my routes in this manner:

www.domain.com/{culture}/{controller}/{action}...and some params
and
www.domain.com/{controller}/{action}... (same, but without culture specified)

The problem is that I don't know how to identify user's (browser's) default culture in this way.

As I know I have only two options when using attribute routing:

- optional parameter {culture?}
- default value {culture=en}

but both are not enough to get user's culture when it is not given directly in URI

Answer (score 0):

You may use the value of Accept-Language HTTP header in case that URL doesn't contain culture parameter.

It is accessible through `Request.UserLanguages[]` property so if your client is browser most certainly you will be able to retrieve client's culture by something like:

```
if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages != null && HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages.Any())
{
    var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(Request.UserLanguages[0]);   
}
```

For detailed info about this header take a look at [W3C document section 14.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

**UPDATE**:

Take a look at this [article](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Mar/27/Auto-Selecting-Cultures-for-Localization-in-ASPNET) by Rick Strahl.

Comment: I know hot to get Request.UserLanguages[]. My question is about how to put that culture in URI using attribute routing.